# file input filename put into textfield

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file

I have an upload function wherein I need to customize the fileinput element in html..
I will need to hide it and replace it with my own button and text inputfield..

my question is, how can I put the filename chosen into my custom text inputfield as a substitute to the inputfield that I've hidden?

here's an initial code:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" name="sandiganFile" id="sandigan" style="display:none"/>
<input type="text" id="sandiganFilename" />
<button type="submit" id="sandiganBrowse" onclick="$('#sandigan').click()">Browse</button>
<button type="button" id="sandiganUpload" name="sandigansubmit" >Upload</button>
```

Comment: You're trying to get the full client-local path? Good luck. That's considered a security hole, so I'm pretty sure all modern browsers go to considerable pains to ensure they don't support that.

Comment: Is requirement to use filename of user selected file from `id="sandigan"` to set value of `id="sandiganFilename"` ? , or replace `id="sandigan"` element with new `input` element having value of filename from selected file of `id="sandigan"` ?

Comment: You can watch `#sandigan` for change, then read its `.value`. You can't *modify* file elements, but they are readable, AFAIK. (But yeah, the path would be obscured.)

Comment: uh no sir,, the name of the file would suffice :D

Comment: Thanks for answering guys hahaha,, solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as mentioned in comments, you cannot get full path, but doable for filename only.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $("#sandigan").on('change', function() {
    var file = $(this).val();
    $("#sandiganFilename").val(file.split('\\').reverse()[0]);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" accept="image/*" name="sandiganFile" id="sandigan" style="display:none" />
<input type="text" id="sandiganFilename" />
<button type="submit" id="sandiganBrowse" onclick="$('#sandigan').click()">Browse</button>
<button type="button" id="sandiganUpload" name="sandigansubmit">Upload</button>
```

Comment: this worked haha thanks,, I could only accept after a  few minutes,,, wait :D

Answer (score 1):

Try utilizing `.change()` , `name` property of `File` object

```js
$("#sandigan").change(function(e) {
  $("#sandiganFilename").val(this.files[0].name);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<input type="file" accept="image/*" name="sandiganFile" id="sandigan" style="display:none"/>
<input type="text" id="sandiganFilename" />
<button type="submit" id="sandiganBrowse" onclick="$('#sandigan').click()">Browse</button>
<button type="button" id="sandiganUpload" name="sandigansubmit" >Upload</button>
```